# Interpolation of scalars

Tags: inequalities

For $a,b$ and $\alpha_i, \beta_i $ where $ i \in \{ 1,2 \} $, are non-negative real numbers, is it possible to find a constant $C$ such that
$$(\alpha_1 a + \beta_1 b) ^{(1-\theta)} (\alpha_2 a + \beta_2 b) ^{\theta} \leq C (\alpha_1 ^{(1-\theta)} \alpha_2^{\theta} a +\beta_1 ^{(1-\theta)} \beta_2^{\theta} b)?$$
for all $\theta \in [0,1]$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is $C$ supposed to be independent of all the other numbers? Then this cannot work, for example when $a=b=1$ and $\beta_1,\alpha_2$ are much larger than the remaining $\alpha_j,\beta_j$.

Comment: I'm not sure what is an appropriate tag, but "nt.number-theory" is definitely not the right tag.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Reading the OP I understand that $C$ may depend on $a, b ,\alpha_i, \beta_i$ but not on $\theta$

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes $C$ supposed to be independent of all the other numbers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\al\alpha\newcommand\be\beta\newcommand\th\theta$Note that for any real $A>0$ and $B>0$ the expression $p(\th):=A^{1-\th}B^\th=A(B/A)^\th$ is monotonic in $\th$. So,
$$\min_{\th\in[0,1]}A^{1-\th}B^\th
=\min_{\th\in[0,1]}p(\th)=\min(p(0),p(1))=\min(A,B)$$ and $$\max_{\th\in[0,1]}A^{1-\th}B^\th=\max_{\th\in[0,1]}p(\th)=\max(p(0),p(1))=\max(A,B).$$
Clearly, the conclusions $\min_{\th\in[0,1]}A^{1-\th}B^\th=\min(A,B)$ and $\max_{\th\in[0,1]}A^{1-\th}B^\th=\max(A,B)$ will still hold for any real $A\ge0$ and $B\ge0$, provided the convention $0^0:=1$.

So,
$$\max_{\th\in[0,1]}(\al_1 a+\be_1 b)^{1-\th}(\al_2 a+\be_2 b)^\th
=\max(\al_1 a+\be_1 b,\al_2 a+\be_2 b)=:L$$
and
$$\min_{\th\in[0,1]} (\al_1^{1-\th}\al_2^\th a+\be_1^{1-\th}\be_2^\th b)
\ge\min(\al_1,\al_2)a+\min(\be_1,\be_2)b=:R.$$

So, the inequality in question,
$$(\al_1 a+\be_1 b)^{1-\th}(\al_2 a+\be_2 b)^\th
\le C (\al_1^{1-\th}\al_2^\th a+\be_1^{1-\th}\be_2^\th b), 
\tag{1}\label{1}$$
will hold for all $\th\in[0,1]$ with $C:=L/R$ provided that $R\ne0$.

Without the condition $R\ne0$, \eqref{1} will not hold for any real $C$ if e.g. $\th=1/2$, $\al_1>0$, $\al_2=0$, $\be_1=0$, $\be_2>0$, $a>0$, $b>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for C to be independent of all the other numbers, which is not possible after the @ChristianRemling's clarification. I'm sorry for did not mention it in the question.